# Add image to pdf with pdfbox on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using pdxbox on google app engine, I use modifed version to be compatible with app engine (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12342272/2459131).

But I'm not able to add image in pdf. Because : `javax.imageio.ImageIO` is a restricted class

I need to make this work :

```
BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read(new File(image));
```

I found two link that can help but I don't know how to use it :
https://github.com/pascalleclercq/appengine-awt/releases/tag/appengine-awt-1.0.0

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport.appengine-awt/appengine-awt/1.0.0 
--> import in my project but `com.google.code.appengine.awt.image.BufferedImage` cannot be use in pdfbox's method

Edit :

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

PDPage tmp = (PDPage) PDDocument.load("WEB-INF/pdfs/TemplateFactureEmpty3.pdf").getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
document.addPage(tmp);
PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(document, tmp, true, true);

// choice 1 , pb : call ImageIO restricted
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("WEB-INF/CokeLogo1.png"));
PDJpeg ximage = new PDJpeg(document, in);

// choise 2 , pb : BufferedImage and ImageIO restricted
BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read(new File("WEB-INF/CokeLogo1.png") );
PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDPixelMap(document, awtImage);

float scale = 1f; // alter this value to set the image size
content.drawXObject(ximage, 56, 800, ximage.getWidth() * scale,ximage.getHeight() * scale);
```

Thanks,
Francois

Comment: please post the whole code for creating the pdf using pdfbox .

Comment: Done, but the problem is not the not it's the lib

Comment: *it's the lib* - well, the PDFBox version you refer to has been created for GAE to **run fine for simple text extraction**. Your task is utterly different. Thus, you obviously have to patch PDFBox some more.

Comment: Hi @Kingstone59 could you solve it? Same issue here